# How did Magneto know Mystique injected the metal into Laurio's body?

Tags: plot-explanation, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-2

In *X2*, Magneto sensed the iron in the guardian Laurio's blood, which was injected by Mystique, and used it to escape the plastic prison. It is normal that he sensed it, since he is, well... Magneto. But how does he know that it was Mystique that injected the iron, or the way she injected it.

> Mr. Laurio, never trust a beautiful woman, especially ones that are
>   interested in you.

Comment: I figure it started before he was caught, when he pulled Mystique aside and said WTE: *"If I ever get imprisoned, follow these instructions.."*

Comment: @AndrewThompson That is actually a likely thought since Magneto has been in a similar situation in past. (as seen in the Days of the Future Past)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Although it's not made quite so obvious in the film, in the original script Laurio entered the scanning chamber (and then the cell) with a **[huge stupid smile on his face](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYItZ.png) and a swagger in his step**. Everyone around him puts 1+1 together and immediately spots that he got lucky last night.

Since he's got massive amounts of colloidal iron in his bloodstream, Eric then discerns what actually happened to Mr Laurio the night before; A woman slept with him and then (unknowingly) injected him with metal. It's not hard to work out who that woman might be.

---

In the film, they changed the sequence of events slightly, having Magneto be asleep until Laurio entered the chamber then have him wake up by detecting the metal. Although they'd changed the sequence of events, they obviously still kept the line about not trusting a beautiful woman because, heck, it's a good line as well as being generally good advice.

From the [film's script](http://www.scifiscripts.com/scripts/X-Men_2.pdf)

> INT. PLASTIC PRISON - SECURITY CHECKPOINT - DAY   TWO GUARDS stand in
> the room by the door to the catwalk. LAURIO enters carrying a tray of
> food.
>
> **GUARD 1:** *What's that on your face, Mitch?*
>
> **LAURIO:** *Sa-tisfaction.*
>
> The Guard grimaces at the thought of it, and opens the door.
>
> **GUARD 1:** *You're clear.*
>
> INT. PLASTIC PRISON - SAME TIME
>
> Magneto angrily paces back and forth -- thinking about Charles. **He
> stops and looks at Laurio... curiously.**
>
> **LAURIO** (O.S.): *Have a nice sleep, Lensherr?*
>
> Laurio enters and puts the food on a table. **His smile becomes a
> scowl** when he sees Magneto staring at him.
>
> **MAGNETO:** *There's something different about you,*

In the film's [novelisation](http://xmenmovies.wikia.com/wiki/X-Men_2_(novelization)), they chose a middle ground, having Magneto spot the smile on Laurio's face *as he came awake*:

> Mitchell Laurio was whistling as he came on shift. He couldn’t
> remember many of the details of what had happened in the ladies’ can,
> but he’d never felt better in his life than he had after it was done. Just the
> memory of Grace’s farewell kisses was enough to stir his blood and put
> a spring in his step, and the fact that she’d left a whispered promise
> to meet him again tonight made him wish as he never had before for the
> day to end.
>
> The guard at the final checkpoint was the latest to offer comment:
> “Mitchell Laurio, what is that on your face, man?
>
> “Sa-tis- fac-tion!”
>
> ...
>
> Eric Lehnsherr was asleep until Laurio stepped over the threshold.
> Then, just like that, he came completely awake with a rush he hadn’t
> felt since his capture.
>
> “Sweet dreams, Lehnsherr?” asked Laurio, his mockery plain. Just
> because he’d had the best night of his life didn’t mean he was going
> to pass on the morning beating. The one gave him just as much pleasure
> as the other.
>
> Laurio set the tray on the table. Lehnsherr hadn’t moved, beyond
> sitting up on the bed. There was something different about his
> expression, though, like there was a big joke being played here that
> only he was privy to. But at the same time, there was a predatory cast
> to his eyes that made Laurio suddenly wish the internal monitors were
> active and that he were somewhere else.
>
> As was usual for him when he felt ill at ease or threatened, Laurio
> got aggressive. This time, he decided, he wasn’t going to stop until
> the old man begged him.
>
> “There’s something different about you, Mr. Laurio,” Lehnsherr said
> with a slight question to his voice, as if he couldn’t quite credit
> what he saw.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer but, what if the guardian was simply gay, and Mystique had turned into a guy instead? Of course Laurio was far from being concerned about the accuracy of Magneto's suggestions at the time, but we as audience, aren't.

Comment: @SarpSTA - Laurio has been his guard for some time and he doesn't seem to be above lording his freedom over Magneto. It's certainly possible (in fact downright likely) that he's mentioned enough for him to determine his sexuality. Then again he may simply be assuming.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that Magneto can sense magnetizable metal in the same way that birds can, slightly. It's a 6th sense exhibited in many animals.

It is called `Magnetoreception`. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetoreception

Comment: I always assumed it was this, especially because - at one point in one of the movies - Magneto tells Wolverine that he could "sense his adamantium a mile away", which I believe confirms that what you wrote is at least a reasonable possibility.

Comment: Of course, Wolverine is a couple hundred pounds of walking metal. Not a few ounces of iron.

Comment: I don't believe you understood the question. Question is: "How does Magneto know that it is Mystique who injected the metal."